# DateFormatter giving me incorrect result while I am converting String into Date in UK region and Timezone is Muscat

Tags: date, dateformatter

I want `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"`, with time in 24 hour format, but as i m having 12 hrs date format setting in my phone and Timezone is set to the Muscat ,the date which I am getting is always 12 hrs format, while i m checking with UK region. I am able to change `Date()` into string in 24 hrs format but while I am changing 24 hrs string into 24 hrs Date , It always give me 12 hrs Date format

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
let dateToString = dateFormatter.string(from: Date()) //2020-04-06 15:47:16
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
let dateFromString = dateFormatter.date(from: dateToString)
print(dateFromString) // 2020-04-06 1:47:25 pm +0000
```

Comment: Which programming language is that? Please tag your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

A `Date` object just represents a point in time. The “should I show it in 12 hour clock or 24 hour clock” is not something that `Date` objects know about. This is a feature of strings generated by (or consumed by) a `DateFormatter`.

So, a few thoughts:

- A date formatter’s `dateFormat` (and its `locale`) dictates what a string will look like when you call `string(from:)`. (It will also dictate how to interpret a string and create a `Date` object when you call `date(from:)`, but that’s not relevant here.)

  So, if you’re looking for a string representation of a date using a 24 hour clock, look at the string generated by the date formatter’s `string(from:)` method. This is the `dateToString` string in your example.
- But, if you subsequently generate a `Date` object from the formatter’s `date(from:)` method, that resulting `Date` will not capture whether to use 12 vs 24 hour clock. If you `print` this `Date` object, it won’t reflect your 12/24 hour clock preference.

Bottom line, only concern yourself with am/pm vs 24-hour clock when looking at `String` objects generated by (or passed to) the `DateFormatter`. Don’t worry about the format of the output when you print a `Date` object, as that’s for debugging purposes only and won’t capture this am/pm vs 24-hour clock dimension.

You said:

> Final statement is giving me “2020-04-09 4:23:27 am +0000” format.

If you’re seeing the `+0000`, that suggests that you are printing the `Date` object, itself. The `dateFormat` and `locale` of a `DateFormatter` only controls the format of the string generated by `string(from:)` (and how strings are parsed).

So, print the string generated by `DateFormatter`, not `Date` objects. The print of a `Date` object will always be in this predefined format. Within the app, if you need the output in a given format, use the `String` generated by `DateFormatter`, not `Date` objects.

---

Consider a more obvious example of the issue where the `DateFormatter` is used to create a string in a very different format:

```
let now = Date()
print(now)                                   // 2020-04-07 11:54:58 +0000

let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateStyle = .long
formatter.timeStyle = .long
let string = formatter.string(from: Date())
print(string)                                // April 7, 2020 at 4:54:58 AM PDT

if let date = formatter.date(from: string) {
    print(date)                              // 2020-04-07 11:54:58 +0000
}
```

So, even though that formatter successfully converted a `Date` to a `String`, and back, that final `print` statement uses the same fixed format that the first `print` statement did, because I’m just printing a `Date` object. I’m not concerned that the that last `print` statement didn’t honor the configuration of my `DateFormatter`. I wouldn’t expect it to. When I print a `Date`, it’s always in that fixed, predefined format. I only worry about the format of the strings generated by the `DateFormatter` (the second `print` statement).

---

As an aside, there are secondary questions about your `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"` format. What timezone does this represent? Your local timezone? Your server’s timezone? GMT/UTC/Zulu? We often use ISO8601/RFC3339 date strings (like `2020-04-07T11:54:58Z`) to remove this ambiguity. You should get your arms around your original question first, but when you have that behind you, you’ll want to take a hard look at why you’re storing it in this format, and how you want to deal with timezones correctly. But first things first.

Comment: Hi @Rob Thank you so much for your help. Final statement is giving me "2020-04-09 4:23:27 am +0000" format. I need 24 hrs format , my whole project is depends on 24hrs. This format  issue is only generating in UK region.